# Can't run kite in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, kite

Whenever i try to activate my kite and restart my pycharm this message pop up

[kite plugin conflict with code with me : DISABLE AND RESTART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOpnt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Code with me" (CWM) plugin conflicts with Kite. Here is the corresponding ticket in CWM issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-1307

You can disable CWM and enable Kite in "Settings | Plugins".